# Hide BXSlider on desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, desktop, bxslider

I am currently using bx slider for some products. My issue is that i need to disable BX Slider when the screen is desktop width. I have tried with:

```
jQuery(window).resize(function(e) {
    var winwidth = jQuery(window).width();
    if(winwidth < 740){
          jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider();
    }else{

    }
})
```

But that dublicates the slider function (html and all the stuff), and the slider does not show up when the user sizes the window up to desktop size.

Actually i thought about using stopPropagation(); but in this case, i can't get it to work.

Any ideas how to solve this? :)

Comment: @simondunn does that script works?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest check useeragent if its ios or android init bxslider else not. u can use modnizer js also for check device type.

solution for BXslider init base on resize window.

```
var bxslider = null;
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
  var winwidth = $(window).width();         
  if(winwidth < 740){
    bxslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();                               
  }         
});

$(window).resize(function(e) {

    var winwidth = $(window).width();   
     if(bxslider != null && winwidth > 740 ){
         bxslider.destroySlider();       

     }else if(bxslider === null && winwidth < 740 ){
       bxslider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
     }
});
```

Comment: That's a good ideat, though then there will be some problems with the fluid responsive :/

Comment: @SimonDuun I have update code with JS solution which will not disturb fluid responsive.

Comment: Add "bxslider = null;" after "bxslider.destroySlider();"